# AlertDialog don't work well in onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a AlertDialog in a onOptionsItemSelected in a fragment, the first time is working well, but when opened for the second time and I have two options
1. when onOptionsItemselected returns true
Show the previous AlertDialog, and the AlertDialog doesn't work well
2. when onOptionsItemselected returns false
show two or more AlertDialog's, but the first AlertDialog works, but the other appear and they don't do anythyng

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_sortP:

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue, null);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                final RadioGroup radioGroupBy = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.radio_groudBy);
                final RadioGroup radioGroupOr = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.radio_groupOr);

                if (radioButtonIDby != 0){
                    RadioButton radioButtonBy1 = radioGroupBy.findViewById(radioButtonIDby);
                    radioButtonBy1.setChecked(true);
                }
                if (radioButtonIDor != 0){
                    RadioButton radioButtonOr1 = radioGroupOr.findViewById(radioButtonIDor);
                    radioButtonOr1.setChecked(true);
                }

                Button buttonCancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                Button button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        radioButtonIDby = radioGroupBy.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        radioButtonIDor = radioGroupOr.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                        if (radioButtonIDby == R.id.radio_nombre && radioButtonIDor == R.id.radio_asc){
                            Collections.sort(listLugares, new Comparator<LugarTuristico>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(LugarTuristico o1, LugarTuristico o2) {
                                    return o1.getName_lugar().compareTo(o2.getName_lugar());
                                }
                            });
                        }else if(radioButtonIDby == R.id.radio_nombre && radioButtonIDor == R.id.radio_desc){
                            Collections.sort(listLugares, new Comparator<LugarTuristico>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(LugarTuristico o1, LugarTuristico o2) {
                                    return o2.getName_lugar().compareTo(o1.getName_lugar());
                                }
                            });
                        }else if(radioButtonIDby == R.id.radio_tipo && radioButtonIDor == R.id.radio_asc){
                            Collections.sort(listLugares, new Comparator<LugarTuristico>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(LugarTuristico o1, LugarTuristico o2) {
                                    return o1.getTipo_lugar().compareTo(o2.getTipo_lugar());
                                }
                            });
                        }else if(radioButtonIDby == R.id.radio_tipo && radioButtonIDor == R.id.radio_desc){
                            Collections.sort(listLugares, new Comparator<LugarTuristico>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(LugarTuristico o1, LugarTuristico o2) {

                                    return o2.getTipo_lugar().compareTo(o1.getTipo_lugar());
                                }
                            });
                        }else if(radioButtonIDby == R.id.radio_valoracion && radioButtonIDor == R.id.radio_asc){
                            Collections.sort(listLugares, new Comparator<LugarTuristico>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(LugarTuristico o1, LugarTuristico o2) {
                                    return new Double(o2.getValoracion()).compareTo(new Double(o1.getValoracion()));
                                }
                            });
                        }else if(radioButtonIDby == R.id.radio_valoracion && radioButtonIDor == R.id.radio_desc){
                            Collections.sort(listLugares, new Comparator<LugarTuristico>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(LugarTuristico o1, LugarTuristico o2) {
                                    return new Double(o1.getValoracion()).compareTo(new Double(o2.getValoracion()));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        setAdaptadorRVLista(listLugares);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Just update the first time, but I open for second time, don't work or acumulate AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Try with dialog.cancel(); instead of dismiss